# Logitech Lua script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

im trying to run this script on my logitech mouse. I want the mouse cursor to move down, it does but after a while of the cursor moving down the cursor reverses in direction.

Does anyone know why?

```
function X4()
local mult= 11
  if IsMouseButtonPressed(1)then 
    repeat 
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 11*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 11*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 11*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 11*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 10*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 11*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 11*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 12*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 13*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 14*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 14*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 14*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 14*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 14*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 14*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 15*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        MoveMouseRelative(0*mult, 16*mult)Sleep(10) if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mouse move simulation should be in a reasonable limits.
It's very unrealistic that a human can move mouse cursor faster than 100 pixels in 10 ms.

`MoveMouseRelative` accepts only integers in the range `-127..127`
In your case `16*mult = 16*11 = 176 > 127`
Values above 127 might be interpreted as negative values.